# help me to solve the string condition in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Departmentid   parentid
2          52630    
8          52630    
14         52630    
20         52630    
26         52630

declare @retstr varchar(8000)  
Select Top 5 @retstr =  COALESCE(@retstr + ',','') +''''+
   convert     (varchar,departmentid)
   +''''  
       from Department  where ParentId =52630
print @retstr
```

I get the following result

Output :  '2','8','14','20','26'

@retstr have '2','8','14','20','26' value, using IN operator i check the condition

```
Select * from product
        INNER JOIN [DepartmentProduct] dp ON p.productid=dp.productid
        INNER JOIN [Department] d ON d.DepartmentId = dp.DepartmentId
        INNER JOIN [ProductTranslation] pt ON p.ProductId = pt.ProductId AND pt.LocaleId = 1             
  WHERE **d.department in (@retstr)**
```

It throws following error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to
>   bigint.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a bigint to a string in your second query.  What you would want to do is use a subquery instead of saving it as a string.

```
    select * 
      from product 
INNER JOIN [DepartmentProduct] dp ON p.productid=dp.productid 
INNER JOIN [Department] d ON d.DepartmentId = dp.DepartmentId 
INNER JOIN [ProductTranslation] pt ON p.ProductId = pt.ProductId AND pt.LocaleId = 1 
     WHERE d.department in (Select Top 5 departmentid
                              from Department where ParentId =52630)
```

Answer (score 0):

@retstr is a VARCHAR, so your query is actually

WHERE d.department in (**'''2'',''8''...'**)

The IN list should be separate int/bigints,not a single string masquerading as a list.  SQL Server does not support array/list types by the way.

What you need to do is simply make the first query a subquery of the 2nd

```
Select *
from product
INNER JOIN [DepartmentProduct] dp ON p.productid=dp.productid
INNER JOIN [Department] d ON d.DepartmentId = dp.DepartmentId
INNER JOIN [ProductTranslation] pt ON p.ProductId = pt.ProductId AND pt.LocaleId = 1
WHERE d.department in (
    Select Top 5 departmentid
    from Department
    where ParentId =52630
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the IN operator is expecting a list of values the same type as d.department, i.e. a list of integers. @restr

You can rewrite this as one query, as described in the other answers, and I would recommend that. If you need to keep it as separate queries,  can use dynamic SQL:

```
@sql = 'Select * from product INNER JOIN [DepartmentProduct] dp ON p.productid=dp.productid INNER JOIN [Department] d ON d.DepartmentId = dp.DepartmentId INNER JOIN [ProductTranslation] pt ON p.ProductId = pt.ProductId AND pt.LocaleId = 1 WHERE d.department in ('+@retstr+')'
```

You can then use ExecSQL(@sql) to execute the query.